# Making string sets become a data frame sorted by group, containing sequence information

Tags: r

I am striving to make an organized data frame out of strings.

with this input

```
text = c('I do not want to do this thing anymore','you do not know what I mean','I will not do this thing','do not want anymore','you will see')

[1] "I do not want to do this thing anymore" "you do not know what I mean"           
[3] "I will not do this thing"               "do not want anymore"                   
[5] "you will see"
```

I hope to make a data frame which seems sort of Document Term Table having sequence information. However, I have no idea how to fulfill this. This is neither Document-Term Matrix nor just a data frame which can be made with the code below.

```
as.data.frame(t(stri_list2matrix(strsplit(as.character(text),' '))))

   V1   V2   V3      V4   V5    V6   V7    V8      V9
1   I   do  not    want   to    do this thing anymore
2 you   do  not    know what     I mean  <NA>    <NA>
3   I will  not      do this thing <NA>  <NA>    <NA>
4  do  not want anymore <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>    <NA>
5 you will  see    <NA> <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>    <NA>
```

What I aim to make is this

```
    V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9  V10  V11   V12     V13  V14  V15  V16
1 <NA>    I   do <NA>  not <NA> <NA> want   to   do this thing anymore <NA> <NA> <NA>
2  you <NA>   do <NA>  not <NA> know <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>    <NA> what    I mean
3 <NA>    I <NA> will  not <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>   do this thing    <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
4 <NA> <NA>   do <NA>  not <NA> <NA> want <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA> anymore <NA> <NA> <NA>
5  you <NA> <NA> will <NA>  see <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>    <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>

result = data.frame(V1=c(NA,"you",NA,NA,"you"),
                    V2=c("I",NA,"I",NA,NA),
                    V3=c("do","do",NA,"do",NA),
                    V4=c(NA,NA,"will",NA,"will"),
                    V5=c("not","not","not","not",NA),
                    V6=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"see"),
                    V7=c(NA,"know",NA,NA,NA),
                    V8=c("want",NA,NA,"want",NA),
                    V9=c("to",NA,NA,NA,NA),
                    V10=c("do",NA,"do",NA,NA),
                    V11=c("this",NA,"this",NA,NA),
                    V12=c("thing",NA,"thing",NA,NA),
                    V13=c("anymore",NA,NA,"anymore",NA),
                    V14=c(NA,"what",NA,NA,NA),
                    V15=c(NA,"I",NA,NA,NA),
                    V16=c(NA,"mean",NA,NA,NA))
```

so that I can revert original string lists like this.

```
origin = do.call(paste, c(result, sep=" "))
origin = gsub('( NA|NA\\s*)','',origin)
origin

[1] "I do not want to do this thing anymore" "you do not know what I mean"           
[3] "I will not do this thing"               "do not want anymore"                   
[5] "you will see"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code and let me know if this serves your purpose, just the order of words is different in the output data frame from yours

```
library(stringi)
text = c('I do not want to do this thing anymore','you do not know what I mean','I will not do this thing','do not want anymore','you will see')

tf = as.data.frame(t(stri_list2matrix(strsplit(as.character(text),' '))),stringsAsFactors = F)
strs = unlist(strsplit(as.character(text),' '))

fstrs = unique(strs)

fdf = data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(fstrs),nrow = 0))
names(fdf) = fstrs

log_out = data.frame()
for(i in 1:nrow(tf)){

  log = as.data.frame(t(names(fdf)[ifelse((names(fdf) %in% as.character(tf[i,])) == F,NA,T)]))
  log_out = rbind(log_out,log)
}
```

And the output will be

```
log_out
    V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6    V7      V8   V9  V10  V11  V12  V13  V14
1    I   do  not want   to this thing anymore <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2    I   do  not <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>    <NA>  you know what mean <NA> <NA>
3    I   do  not <NA> <NA> this thing    <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> will <NA>
4 <NA>   do  not want <NA> <NA>  <NA> anymore <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
5 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>    <NA>  you <NA> <NA> <NA> will  see
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it can not handle second one - 'you do not know what I mean'. It is cool, though.

Comment: Your expectation is that words to be split in existing order from each sentence with repetition of words? If so, any other rule you wanna add here like when this repetition should stop?

Comment: Well... The rule is also the part of what I am looking for. It is really perplexing.